# prevent nested for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

this is my JSON file and i want to create HTML multi level menu without nested loops

```
[{"text":"Home","href":"http://home.com","icon":"fas fa-home","target":"_top","title":"My Home"},{"text":"Posts","href":"","icon":"fas fa-bell","target":"_self","title":"","children":[{"text":"Sports","href":"","icon":"empty","target":"_self","title":""},{"text":"IT1","href":"","icon":"empty","target":"_self","title":""},{"text":"Web","href":"","icon":"","target":"_self","title":""},{"text":"About","href":"","icon":"fas fa-chart-bar","target":"_self","title":""}]}]
```

i wrote this but i think its not the best way to do that
thanks for helping

```
        function MenuToHTML(JSON) {
            let html = "<ul>";
            for (items in JSON) {
                html += "<li>";
                //console.log(JSON[items].text);
                html += JSON[items].text;
                if (JSON[items].hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                    var child = JSON[items].children;
                    html += "<ul>";
                    for (subItems in child) {
                        html += "<li>";
                        html += child[subItems].text;
                        if (child[subItems].hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                            html += "<ul>";
                            var child = child[subItems].children;
                            for (SubsubItems in child) {
                                html += "<li>";
                                html += child[SubsubItems].text;
                                html += "</li>";
                            }
                            html += "</ul>";
                        }
                        html += "</li>";
                    }
                    html += "</ul>";
                }
                html += "</li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>";
            return html;
        }
```

Comment: you should use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You donot need to create nested loops like that use `recursion` and for `arrays` use for `for..of` or `forEach` instead of `for..in`

```js
let arr = [
 {"text":"Home","href":"http://home.com","icon":"fas fa-home","target":"_top","title":"My Home"},
 {"text":"Posts","href":"","icon":"fas fa-bell","target":"_self","title":"","children":
  [{"text":"Sports","href":"","icon":"empty","target":"_self","title":""},
  {"text":"IT1","href":"","icon":"empty","target":"_self","title":""},
  {"text":"Web","href":"","icon":"","target":"_self","title":""},
  {"text":"About","href":"","icon":"fas fa-chart-bar","target":"_self","title":""}]}
]


/*this function will convert an array to html list. So you can pass the children 
array again to the same function and it will to convert children to html list*/
function MenuToHTML(JSON) {
     let html = "<ul>";
  JSON.forEach(item => {
  html += `<li>${item.text}</li>`;
  if(item.children){
   html += MenuToHTML(item.children); 
  }
 })
 return html + '</ul>';
}
document.body.innerHTML = MenuToHTML(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build real elements and use a recursion for nested children.

```js
function getMenu(array) {
    return array.reduce((ul, { text, href, icon, target, title, children }) => {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            a;

        if (href) {
            a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = href;
            a.target = target;
            a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            a.title = title;
            li.appendChild(a);
        } else {
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        }
        if (children) {
            li.appendChild(getMenu(children));
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
        return ul;
    }, document.createElement('ul'));
}

var data = [{ text: "Home", href: "http://home.com", icon: "fas fa-home", target: "_top", title: "My Home" }, { text: "Posts", href: "", icon: "fas fa-bell", target: "_self", title: "", children: [{ text: "Sports", href: "", icon: "empty", target: "_self", title: "" }, { text: "IT1", href: "", icon: "empty", target: "_self", title: "" }, { text: "Web", href: "", icon: "", target: "_self", title: "" }, { text: "About", href: "", icon: "fas fa-chart-bar", target: "_self", title: "" }] }];

document.body.appendChild(getMenu(data));
```